# Django update form generate false date

Tags: django, timezone

I created a calendar app in django where I can add/update/delete events (include startdate, enddate and title).

I have a problem now when I try to update a event. For example I want to update the startdate from 2015-02-04 to 2015-02-03 the value of the startdate is always saved with -1 day (2015-02-02).

my model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

my form:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

my view:

```
form = EventForm(
    request.POST,
    instance=Event.objects.get(
        pk=request.POST['id']
    )
 )
form.save()
```

small explanation:
When I want to update an event I send the ID within the request so I can inject the old instance of the event into the form.

I know there must be an issue with timezone. In my settings.py I have USE_TZ = True and TIME_ZONE='EUrope/Prague'.

The request.POST['start'] contains strings like '2015-02-03'

When I check what is saved in my DB (Events.objects.all()) I can see that the dates are saved with UTC.

```
events = Event.objects.all()
e = events[0]
e.start
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 2, 11, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DateField instead of DateTimeField, as you are not using time ?